# Joint use of "for" and "if" operators in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to gather all non-factors from a dataframe **d3** and put them into the table **m**

```
for (i in 1:12) {
  m<-as.data.frame(matrix(100,nrow = nrow(d3),ncol = ncol(d3)))
  if (!is.factor(d3[,i])){
    m[,i]<-d3[,i]
    }
  }
```

For specific values of i (e.g. if i=2) , I get what I want. But looping does not work. Where do I make a mistake in code above?

Comment: You can experiment with the **mutate_if** function from the **dplyr** package. Something similar to the following should work **m <- d3 %>% dplyr::mutate_if(!is.factor) %>% as.table()**

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and describe what you mean by "but looping does not work".

Comment: and providing the `d3` data would be a big help.

Answer (score 4):

You're recreating `m` each time through the loop; it should be outside.

```
m <- as.data.frame(matrix(100, nrow = nrow(d3), ncol = ncol(d3)))
for (i in 1:12) {
  if (!is.factor(d3[, i])) {
    m[, i] <- d3[, i]
  }
}
```

But you really should just be using vectorized operations to do it all at once.

```
nonf <- !sapply(d3, is.factor)
m[, nonf] <- d3[, nonf]
```